# AppDelegate continue UserActivity is not called when app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift5

I am working on Universal links in iOS (swift 5).

**case 1**)
when the app is in a background state and when I tapped on the link ([www.mydomain.com/dashboard](http://www.mydomain.com/dashboard))
The app opens and the AppDelegates method (continue user activity) called **(working fine)**

**case 2**)
but when the app is closed or killed and when I tapped on the link
The app opens and the AppDelegates method (continue user activity) not called.**(Not Working)**

I check all answers on the internet but not get a proper Answer.
I want my app to be open when the user tabbed on Link. It is working in the background case. but did not work in Closed App

Comment: I see in your profile that your experience is with Android. Mine's with iOS, and I know next to nothing about Android. If you look through `AppDelegate` (and anymore, `SceneDelegate`) you'll find some pretty clear explanations about when each method is executed. What troubles me in your question is the use of *"closed"*. Generally speaking, users do not "close" apps in iOS, they just "jump" to another app (via a few ways), sending the previous app into the background. Yes, there are ways for "quit" and app - but why would you think that would trigger the same calls?

Comment: I worked on Both Technologies iOS/Android.  Actually, I am working on Deep Links in iOS. I want my app to be open when the user tabbed on Link. It is working in the background case. but did not worked in Closed App

Comment: I understand that. But when the app is closed, why would you expect the same exact sequence of methods to be executed? BTW, what `AppDelegate` method are you expecting to be executed? Since iOS 13, there are 3 methods in `AppDelegate` (with two related to Scenes, and 3 methods in `SceneDelegate`. Maybe if you post some code as to how/what this "continue user activity" works, it might help.